# Google maps event after custom tiles loaded

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem. I am loading custom map tiles using overlayMapTypes.insertAt() AKA MVCArray.insertAt() and i need to know then my tiles are loaded.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
        if (map.overlayMapTypes.getLength() == 0) {
            map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, new ItemsMapType(new google.maps.Size(256, 256)));
        }
});
```

Is there event that fires after that or something? 
p.s idle event fires too soon.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score -1):

have you checked https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Comment: problem was that tiles were loaded using ajax async so i made my custom event, that fires then ajax_started_count - ajax_finnished_count = 0